# how to add items to TreeViewAdv in multi-column mode with winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I was playing around with this control called [TreeViewAdv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/treeviewadv/). I've already added the control and added couple of columns trying to see how it works. but till now when I add items to the control all I get is empty nodes. the example provided with the control is not clear at all and it just gave me headaches when I try to figure out how the data is being added to it. anyway here is what I've done so far and I hope that someone can guide me to the right direction.

```
    TreeModel _model = new TreeModel();
    treeViewAdv1.Model = _model;

    treeViewAdv1.BeginUpdate();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {

        Node parentNode = new Node("root" + i);
        _model.Nodes.Add(parentNode);

        for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++)
        {
            Node childNode = new MyNode("child" + n);
            parentNode.Nodes.Add(childNode); 
        }

    }

    treeViewAdv1.EndUpdate();
```

anyway, all I'm getting is empty nodes and I really can't figure out how to add data to the other columns... any help would be appreciated...

Comment: It may be good to point out here that the input for the TreeNodeAdv.Tag property is the Node.Text property and not Node.Tag. Very confusing in my opinion, but I found out after a while.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously this questions is old, but I was unable to find any answers to this question, so I figured I would try to save someone some future frustration.

To get multiple columns to display, first change the UseColumns property to true.
Then add desired columms to the Columns collection property.
Next using the NodeControls collection property to create a list of the types of data that will be shown, and how they should be formatted (Checkbox, TextBox, etc).  Make sure to set 1) the DataPropertyName (will be used later), 2) the ParentColumn (to show which column in the treeView is supposed to show the data.
Finally, create a new class inheriting from the Node class, and add a public property with the same name as each NodeControl.  Then when adding Nodes, use your new class with the correct value.

```
 private class ColumnNode: Node
        {
            public string NodeControl1="";  // This sould make the DataPropertyName specified in the Node Collection.
            public string NodeControl2 = "";
            public string NodeControl3 = "";
            public ColumnNode(string nodeControl1, string nodeControl2, int nodeControl3)
            {
                NodeControl1 = nodeControl1;
                NodeControl2 = nodeControl2;
                NodeControl3 = nodeControl3.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Then when adding the 
    TreeModel _model = new TreeModel();

```
_treeViewAdv.Model = _model;
_treeViewAdv.BeginUpdate();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{

    Node parentNode = new ColumnNode("root" + i, "",0);
    _model.Nodes.Add(parentNode);

    for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++)
    {
        Node childNode = new ColumnNode("child" + n,"Further Information",1);
        parentNode.Nodes.Add(childNode); 
    }

}
_treeViewAdv.EndUpdate();
```

For reference, the designer code for the treeViewAdv in this case would look like this:

```
private Aga.Controls.Tree.TreeViewAdv _treeViewAdv;
private Aga.Controls.Tree.TreeColumn Column1;
private Aga.Controls.Tree.TreeColumn Column2;
private Aga.Controls.Tree.TreeColumn Column3;
private Aga.Controls.Tree.NodeControls.NodeTextBox NodeControl1;
private Aga.Controls.Tree.NodeControls.NodeTextBox NodeControl2;
private Aga.Controls.Tree.NodeControls.NodeTextBox NodeControl3;

private InitializeComponent()
{     
    // Left out all other initialization, since this was long enough already.
    this.treeViewAdvPrint = new Aga.Controls.Tree.TreeViewAdv();
    this.Column1 = new Aga.Controls.Tree.TreeColumn();
    this.Column2 = new Aga.Controls.Tree.TreeColumn();
    this.Column3 = new Aga.Controls.Tree.TreeColumn();
    this.NodeControl1 = new Aga.Controls.Tree.NodeControls.NodeTextBox();
    this.NodeControl2 = new Aga.Controls.Tree.NodeControls.NodeTextBox();
    this.NodeControl3= new Aga.Controls.Tree.NodeControls.NodeTextBox();

    // 
    // _treeViewAdv
    // 
    this._treeViewAdv.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
    this._treeViewAdv.Columns.Add(this.Column1);
    this._treeViewAdv.Columns.Add(this.Column2);
    this._treeViewAdv.Columns.Add(this.Column3);
    this._treeViewAdv.DefaultToolTipProvider = null;
    this._treeViewAdv.DragDropMarkColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    this._treeViewAdv.GridLineStyle = ((Aga.Controls.Tree.GridLineStyle)((Aga.Controls.Tree.GridLineStyle.Horizontal | Aga.Controls.Tree.GridLineStyle.Vertical)));
    this._treeViewAdv.LineColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark;
    this._treeViewAdv.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
    this._treeViewAdv.Model = null;
    this._treeViewAdv.Name = "_treeViewAdv";
    this._treeViewAdv.NodeControls.Add(NodeControl1);
    this._treeViewAdv.NodeControls.Add(NodeControl2);
    this._treeViewAdv.NodeControls.Add(NodeControl3);
    this._treeViewAdv.SelectedNode = null;
    this._treeViewAdv.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(443, 356);
    this._treeViewAdv.TabIndex = 6;
    this._treeViewAdv.Text = "_treeViewAdv";
    this._treeViewAdv.UseColumns = true;

    // 
    // Column1
    // 
    this.Column1.Header = "Column 1";
    this.Column1.SortOrder = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.None;
    this.Column1.TooltipText = null;
    this.Column1.Width = 290;
    // 
    // Column3
    // 
    this.Column3.Header = "Column 3";
    this.Column3.SortOrder = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.None;
    this.Column3.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    this.Column3.TooltipText = null;
    // 
    // Column2
    // 
    this.Column2.Header = "Column 2";
    this.Column2.SortOrder = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.None;
    this.Column2.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    this.Column2.TooltipText = null;
    this.Column2.Width = 91;
    // 
    // NodeControl1
    // 
    this.NodeControl1.DataPropertyName = "NodeControl1";
    this.NodeControl1.IncrementalSearchEnabled = true;
    this.NodeControl1.LeftMargin = 3;
    this.NodeControl1.ParentColumn = this.Column1;
    // 
    // NodeControl2
    // 
    this.NodeControl2.DataPropertyName = "NodeControl2";
    this.NodeControl2.IncrementalSearchEnabled = true;
    this.NodeControl2.LeftMargin = 3;
    this.NodeControl2.ParentColumn = this.Column2;
    // 
    // NodeControl3
    // 
    this.NodeControl3.DataPropertyName = "NodeControl3";
    this.NodeControl3.IncrementalSearchEnabled = true;
    this.NodeControl3.LeftMargin = 3;
    this.NodeControl3.ParentColumn = this.Column3;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you're still struggling with the issue, or anyone else is having the same trouble: the solution to empty nodes is to assign a view component to tree.

TreeViewAdv uses MVC, and it requires that you assign a view, though this is not obvious from the example project. NodeTextBox class under NodeControls folder in the source of the TreeViewAdv is one of the viewers you can use. You need to add it to your form and connect it to tree control through its DataPropertyName attribute like this:

```
this._tBox.DataPropertyName = "Text";
```

where _tBox is the NodeTextBox instance. Needless to say, I've just lost hours figuring this out. Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though the price of entry for using this fantastic control is hours, and hours, of head scratching frustration.

This is what you need to do:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeModel _model = new TreeModel();
    treeViewAdv1.Model = _model;

    treeViewAdv1.BeginUpdate();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {

        Node parentNode = new Node("root" + i);
        _model.Nodes.Add(parentNode);

        for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++)
        {
            Node childNode = new Node("child" + n);
            parentNode.Nodes.Add(childNode);
        }

    }

    NodeTextBox ntb = new NodeTextBox();
    ntb.DataPropertyName = "Text";       
    this.treeViewAdv1.NodeControls.Add(ntb);

    treeViewAdv1.EndUpdate();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your columns first, then attach them to the TreeView. After all add new cells in all columns at same cell index.
Hope to help